# Find of the ID of a link from url hash

Tags: jquery

If an anchor link is clicked, it finds the link and adds a `.anchor_highlight` class.

Which works fine, I'm trying to simulate this if the user arrives at this anchor from another page by watching the url.

WORKS for links of current page:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
            $('a[href=*"' + hash + '"]').addClass("anchor_highlight");
        });
```

My attempt by watching the url and using the hash:

```
    $(function(){
     var hash = window.location.hash;

    $('a[href=" + hash + "').addClass("anchor_highlight");
    });
```

The error I receive now is:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=*"#Noise"]`

Any thoughts would be great.

I found my error.

This works, but is there any reason no to do it this way?

`$('a' + hash + '').addClass("anchor_highlight");`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `*` as in the first code and concatenate properly:

```
$('a[href=*"' + hash + '"').addClass("anchor_highlight");
```